# sliding stop on hover - responsive-slider.js ( w3widgets)

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm working on a project and currently I have use http://w3widgets.com/responsive-slider/ this plugin for slider but when I'm hover on banner that is stop auto moving my working project is http://syruptest.com/lotus/dev/

Answer (score 0):

I didnt see anything in the options in your slider, to turn it off.

You could try this one, that has this option: http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/

`pauseOnHover: false,` //Boolean: Pause the slideshow when hovering over slider, then resume when no longer hovering

hope it helps.

Comment: thnks for reply reyaner :), but I've fixed my issue :)